# Failure in running maven

Tags: java, maven

i've installed maven in my PC. and i've followed the instruction on this web http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation.html , but when i would try to run it in command line (as written), i've got BUILD FAILURE error just like this picture below.

[image]

How can i solve this problem? Thanks for any response

Btw, my other question, is there any documentation of configurating java application into guvnor? i'm so grateful if anyone knows about this. :)

Comment: You should post the whole output. Not just "BUILD FAILURE".

Comment: Maven usually tells you why you got BUILD FAILURE. Maybe you got a compile error, maybe your unit tests failed, maybe there's some error in your pom.xml?

Comment: how can i check my pom.xml? Because i really don't know where it is put in. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a goal for the build. Check this for more info http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a goal for maven to run, so it does not know what to do with the project.

Maven  relies on a certain lifecycle, ie an order of so called goals to accomplish its tasks, for example "clean" to empty the current target folder, "install" to compile, test, package and copy the jars into your local respository. To get into the details, read up this [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Since the error message does not differ, another error might be that you entered the command in a folder where no valid pom file is located. If you entered a complete maven command with goals, this would be the next bet.